# Django / DRF - Invalid syntax in a Response object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

everyone.

I want to make a test in DRF. I follow this guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Uy8NZsUfF0&t=3341s&ab_channel=JayCoding

Here I have a Response object:
https://youtu.be/4Uy8NZsUfF0?t=3333

```
return Response('test': self.get_serializer(test, context={'request': self.request}).data, 'last_question_id':last_question)
```

And I get "Invalid syntax" on colons.

But in video it works.

When I change string to this:

```
return Response(self.get_serializer(test, context={'request': self.request}).data, last_question)
```

It works well.
What should I change to make it work? Thank you.

Comment: I think you are missing curly braces around response object, `return Response( { 'test': self.get_serializer(test, context={'request': self.request}).data, 'last_question_id':last_question } )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please to try this :

```
return Response( {  'test': self.get_serializer(test, context={'request': self.request}).data, 
                    'last_question_id':last_question } )
```